# App rejected for Guideline 2.5.14 - Performance - Software Requirements

Tags: audio, app-store-connect, audio-recording, recording

My app was rejected by Apple because of Guideline 2.5.14 - Performance - Software Requirements, apparently I need to add something on top of what I have to meet the requirement. My app's purpose is to record practice sessions for music students and a timer goes off when they tap "Start Recording". I do ask for permission to use their microphone and App Review states that I need a clear visual indicator of the app recording and implement the required means of indicating the recording activity to all parties. Here is my code and thank you in advance helping a newbie out!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation



class NewPracticeSessionViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfRecords
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
        
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    
    var fileName = "audio_file.m4a"
    var numberOfRecords: Int = 0
    var timer: Timer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        if let number: Int = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "my number") as? Int {
            numberOfRecords = number
        }
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { hasPermission in
            if hasPermission {

                print("accepted")
            } else {
                print("denied")
            }
        }
        
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,
                                               target: self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.updateAudioMeter(_:)),
                                               userInfo: nil,
                                               repeats: true)
    }
    
    //MARK: - FUNCTIONS
    
    func getDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
    
        // Display Alert
    
    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default,handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func updateAudioMeter(_ timer: Timer) {
        
        if let recorder = self.audioRecorder {
            if recorder.isRecording {
                let min = Int(recorder.currentTime / 60)
                let sec = Int(recorder.currentTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
                let s = String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
                timeLabel.text = s
                recorder.updateMeters()
                //graphics
                //var apc0 = recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0)
                //var peak0 = recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)
            }
        }
    }
 
    
    @IBAction func recordingPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if audioRecorder == nil {
            numberOfRecords += 1
            let fileName = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecords).m4a")
            
            let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 12000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]
            
            // Start Audio Recording
            
            do {
                audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileName, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder.delegate = self
                try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.record)
                audioRecorder.record()
                
                buttonLabel.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
                audioRecorder.record()
                
            } catch {
                displayAlert(title: "Error", message: "Cannot start the recording")
            }
        } else {
            
            // Stop the recording
            do {
                audioRecorder.stop()
                audioRecorder = nil
                
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
                try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                myTableView.reloadData()
                
                buttonLabel.setTitle("Start Recording", for: .normal)
            } catch {
                displayAlert(title: "Error", message: "Cannot stop the recording")
            }
        }
    }
}
```